# Crash when creating Activity

Tags: android

Good evening Stack !

I have started to learn Android development as a hobby and I am now trying to develop my first "real" application (I have made already only five simple applications from books).

In this application, I have two buttons that will "create" the same Activity but by using two different objects from the same base class, hence allowing me to customize the behavior of the application depending on the button that was clicked.
However, when I am trying to create the Intent instance, my application crashes.

Here is the code of the base Activity class

```
public class BaseDictionnaryActivity extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.basedictionnary);
    }

    public void onDestroy() 
    {   
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

and here is the code that crashes. The line is the one creating the Intent object.

```
public class DictionnaryActivity extends Activity 
{
    private BaseDictionnaryActivity jlpt1;
    private BaseDictionnaryActivity jlpt2;

    private Button btjlpt1 = null;
    private Button btjlpt2 = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dictionnary);

        jlpt2 = new BaseDictionnaryActivity();
        jlpt1 = new BaseDictionnaryActivity();

        btJLPT1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.jlpt1);
        btJLPT1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(DictionnaryActivity.this,   
                                             jlpt1.getClass());
                jlpt1.this.startActivity(myIntent); 
            }
        }); 
        btJLPT2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.jlpt2);
        btJLPT2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(DictionnaryActivity.this, 
                                             jlpt2.getClass());
                jlpt2.this.startActivity(myIntent); 
            }
        });
     }
     public void onDestroy() 
     {   
          super.onDestroy();
     }
}
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to make correction,

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(DictionnaryActivity.this,   
                                         jlpt1.getClass());
```

In this the second argument must be, your target activity `BaseDictionnaryActivity.class`

So, it looks something like,

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(DictionnaryActivity.this,   
                                         BaseDictionnaryActivity.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Also please make sure there will be entry of BaseDictionnaryActivity in your Application's manifest file,

Which is look like,

```
<activity android:name=".BaseDictionnaryActivity"
         ....>
 </activity>
```

Comment: Also you can use `startActivity(myIntent);` As its a method of Activity you can access in other inner methods directly.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. The manifest is correct, I kept the new activity being in it. In order to keep a different behavior between the different instances of the Activity, should I do it through the Intent object ? Or maybe through a different question to the Stack. Please advise :)

Comment: Means? I didn't get you. Pls elaborate more.

Comment: Sorry for that. I would like to open an Activity that display a list which its content is loaded from a file. The file name would be different depending on the button that is clicked. However, I would like to keep the same Activity class as base since only the contents differs. I thought I could do that through different Activity object created in a different way through the constructor

Comment: No need to create a different Activity. Also you can not make a constructor of Activity. Just use Intent for passing different file names to the same activity. And change UI accordingly it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Maybe:
Intent myIntent = new Intent(DictionnaryActivity.this,   
                                         BaseDictionnaryActivity.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(DictionnaryActivity.this, 
                                             NextActivity.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(DictionnaryActivity.this, 
                                         jlpt2.class);
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You need to provide next activity .class in second argument of Intent.

Answer (score 0):

Replace jlpt1.getClass() with NameOfClassToBeLaunched.class 
Also this is bad practice to create Activity instances in other activities.

Comment: Hi Trickster, thank you for you reply. Could you tell me what is the best practice to go from one activity to another one ?

Comment: Fragments can fulfil those needs. BTW, why are you creating activity instances I didn't see any method call using those instances.

Comment: I can't use fragments since I am using 2.3.3 version (yeah old phone...). I was thinking creating different activity version would be the best way for me since I wanted a different behavior of my GUIs but still that same internal processes.

Comment: You can use fragments through android support package refer these links 
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/support-lib.html

http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html